# Golang - alloc large Wei amount to address

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, golang

Im modifying the puppeth genesis wizard file for my own use case. I want to be able to assign a pre-set amount in Wei to a few chosen addresses..

Im having some trouble figuring out how to format the number for these users, i would like to assign 50000000000000000000000000 but keep getting a lot of errors with numbers being too big etc.. anyone know a work around ? the original function looks like this

`genesis.Alloc[*addy] = core.GenesisAccount{
            Balance: new(big.Int).Lsh(big.NewInt(1), 256-7), // 2^256 / 128 (allow many pre-funds without balance overflows)
        }`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of setting a big int:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    value := new(big.Int)
    value.SetString("50000000000000000000000000", 10)
    fmt.Println(value) // 50000000000000000000000000

    // your example generates the incorrect value
    fmt.Println(new(big.Int).Lsh(big.NewInt(1), 256-7)) // 904625697166532776746648320380374280103671755200316906558262375061821325312
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`puppeth` generates static balances for all accounts, based on the logic.
In order to achieve your needs, you need to change genesis file manually after `puppeth` generation